# If $P \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree $n$ then is $P(x+a_0),...P(x+a_n)$ a linearly independent set?

Tags: number-theory

Let $P \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ be of degree $n$ and let $a_0,...,a_n$ be distinct real numbers. Then is $P(x+a_0),...P(x+a_n)$ necessarily a linearly independent set?

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried?

Comment: Actually I had in mind an idea which failed. Anyway, I suggest you to begin with simple cases, as $n=1,2,3$, and look for a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that since $\deg P=n$ we conclude that $(P^{(k)}(x))_{0\le k \le n}$ are linealy independent, because $\deg P^{(k)}=n-k$.

Now, note that by Taylor formula we have
$$P(x+a_j)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_j^k}{k!}P^{(k)}(x)$$
So, if we suppose that 
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\lambda_jP(x+a_j)=0\tag{1}$$
We conclude that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\lambda_ja_j^k\right) P^{(k)}(x)=0$$
Or, using the linear independance of $(P^{(k)}(x))_{0\le k \le n}$, we get
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\lambda_ja_j^k=0,\quad\hbox{for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$}$$
This implies that for every polynomial $Q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nb_kx^k$ we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^n\lambda_jQ(a_j)=\sum_{k=0}^nb_k\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\lambda_ja_j^k\right)=0\tag{2}$$
Now, for $0\le i\le n$,  choose 
$$Q(x)=\ell_i(x)=\prod_{0\le j\le n\atop j\ne i}\frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j}$$
with this choice for $Q$ in $(2)$ we get $\lambda_i=0$. Thus $(1)$ implies that $\lambda_0=\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n$, and the polynomials $(P(x+a_j))_{0\le j\le n}$ are linearly independent.